# EF Add-Migration: connection string issue using app.config

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, connection-string, database-migration

I am trying to learn something about EF step by step by I'm stucked on this since this morning :-|
If I try "Add-Migration" with the follow all works well

```
    public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
         => options.UseSqlServer(@"Server=MyServer;Database=MyDb;User Id=MyUser;Password=MyPsw");   
}
```

But I tried to move the connection string to app.config and modify the above code as follow:

```
 public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
         => options.UseSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db"].ConnectionString);
}
```

I also added "using System.Configuration;"

App.Config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="db"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
         connectionString="Server=MyServer;Database=MyDb;User Id=MyUser;Password=MyPsw"/>
  </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

But in that case it doesn't work and when I try the "Add-Migration" the operation fails and in the PMC appears "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.". What could the problem be?

(I know storing User/psw in app.config is not good, this will be next step to improve...)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this really related to the <sql> language? Perhaps you should have the <sql-server> tag instead?

Comment: you should you appsettings.json

Comment: Do you have a App.Development.Config or other environment specific App.config file that is over-writing your connection strings?

Comment: don't think so, Just started from a WPF empty application add only 3 classes and App.config file..

Comment: Looks like the same issue you have with WPF https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/20091/wpf-core-connection-strings-inside-appconfig-not-w.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i got the ConnectionString. Not sure if this is working for you.

**App.config**

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="con" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=PRWSolution2020;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

**DBContext**

```
public DbSet<Machine> Machines { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ContractDetail> ContractDetails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TimeSheet> TimeSheets { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MachineClient> MachineClients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ServiceReport> ServiceReports { get; set; }

    public PRWContext()
        : base("name=con")
    {

    }
```